# Permission Error Writing to a File with Python Script Launched as PHP/www-data

Tags: php, python, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I have an index.php file that runs a python script as follows:

```
shell_exec("/usr/custom/test.py")
```

The test.py file tries to write to a file (which by default does not exist in the directory) as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import io

with io.FileIO("foobar.txt, "w") as file:
    file.write("Hello!")
```

Now, if I run this file directly as root in Ubuntu, it works fine. The file is created and has "Hello!" inside.

If I run it through the php script (by visiting my index.php page), I get the following error in  /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/custom/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    with io.FileIO("foobar.txt", "w") as file:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'foobar.txt'
```

now...I tried another python file that just prints something and I was able to get that to run fine. So here's where I'm getting confused.

The permissions of the folder and the test.py file is the same and as follows:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 102
```

I can't figure out why this won't let me write to the file. I even tried to create the file first (touch) and then give it permissions...but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Try to get path for file in python to check if it works correctly: create some file inside folder where php file is located, then in python script write `import os` and `print(os.path.abspath("filename.txt"))` - What is the output?

Comment: use `$output = shell_exec("/usr/custom/test.py");` and then print that output to see result of python script.

Comment: Emin, I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking me to do.

So I added the import os and print(os.path.abspath("filename.txt")) into my python test.py script. I also created filename.txt in the same folder as my index.php file  (which was in /var/www/html).

So if I run my python script directly as root it displays /var/www/html/filename.txt

As for your second  comment, I have
 
 $output = shell_exec("/usr/custom/test.py");
 print ($output);

But there is no output on my webpage when  I navigate to the index.php file.  I also don't see anything in the apache log file.

Comment: I should mention I also added print(os.path.abspath("/var/www/html/filename.txt") since I don't  see how python  is going t o find that file from the /usr/custom folder if I just put in  "filename.txt"  as you asked  me to put that file where index.php is which is /var/www/html

Comment: The reason why I asked to add that line without complete path was to check where python tries to create file. If as you said, it checks `/usr/custom/` folder, then it will mean it will try to create `foobar.txt` also inside that directory. Try to give full path for `foobar.txt` while opening file. Also it will be better to use `with open('/path/to/foobar.txt', 'w') as file` instead of `io`.

Comment: Also, make sure it didn't created file `foobar.txt` when you executed python script as root. If it created that file, due to root user, the file will need root access to rewrite. In that case, delete current `foobar.txt` file.

Comment: So I understand what  you are testing now and when I did the test properly, the filename.txt  is actually being created  in the web directory the php file launched it from (/var/www/html) and NOT where the python file is...and where www-data has permissions...

Comment: Hey it works. I made the error of thinking the python file, when launched from the php script, would consider the default directory wherever that python file was located in. Which was incorrect. And you showed me how to test for it. Emin, can you answer this question so I can select your answer as correct? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call that script from php it tries to create file in the same folder as python file itself (in `/usr/custom/`), not php file. To solve that problem, you will need to write absolute path for the file:

```
with open('/var/www/html/foobar.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write("Hello!\n")
```

If you need that file to be created in the same place as your php file, then you will need to pass `path` as an argument in `shell_exec` call. Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) documentation for argument parsing. You can use `getcwd` in php to get path for current directory.

Comment: Thanks, saved me probably another couple hours.